# Set Nolock on SQL tables when reading data from Qlik sense

Tags: sql-server, qliksense

I am working on Qlik sense reading data from SQL server 2016 tables. When reading data Qlik is setting lock on SQL tables which is blocking transactions.

Is there any way to set Nolock in Qlik sense on SQL tables to unblock other transactions. Please advice on how to do.

Comment: Why do you want to? You know what `NOLOCK` does , correct? You know the implications of using it as well?

Comment: You might want to consider using snapshot isolation. It may (or may not) solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for response, Whether it is snapshot isolation or NoLOCK, how do I apply at Qlik Sense so that reading data from SQL from Qlik sense will not block other transactions on SQL

Comment: snapshot isolation is applied at the database level and is automatically used and won't require any Qlik sense changes. If Qlik sense lets you enter the SQL directly then you can just add `with (nolock)` after each table or `set transactional isolation level read uncommitted` at the start. Otherwise there's no way to do it that I'm aware of. Can you edit the SQL statement directly?

Comment: Qlik itself its not performing any locks. Qlik is transparent - it passes the sql "as it is" to the data broker (odbc, oledb etc). in qlik's syntax everything after `SQL` statement is passed for execution form the db. If the sql syntax allows you to write `nolock` (or your db equivalent) just write it after qlik's `SQL` statement and will be passed to the db. Just an example qlik script: `SQL NoLock; select * from my_table;`

Comment: NoLock is not identified in Qlik sense and  I am directly reading table from Qlik sense where I cannot apply isolation level on sql side,

Comment: Can you please paste some code sample?

Comment: I got a solution, call as: Load  * from SQL Select * from Table (NoLock) in ScripLoader

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution,
In ScripLoad Manager:

Instead of using :

Load * from
Select * from Table (NoLock) //giving syntax error

Changed to:

Load  * from 
SQL Select * from Table (NoLock)